# android studio will not intelligently switch overloaded methods

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When you enter the method name, Android Studio will prompt you to choose a different overloading method (with the same function name and different parameters).

For example, I have two functions(It's actually not that simple):

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int){ ... }
fun sum(a: Int){ ... }
```

When I call, enter the function name to select the first function, then I only enter one parameter, and Android Studio will prompt an error, requiring me to enter two parameters.

If I want to call the second function, I must delete the function name, rewrite the function name, and select the second function when prompted by Android Studio.

What did I miss?

#### first edit 2023-4-20

I've found that waiting doesn't solve everything. Android Studio does not seem to be able to automatically obtain Kotlin's extension functions and needs to be selected manually. I think this is the problem I actually ran into.

Comment: Just wait and give it time.  You never need to select any version of a function, anything to do with keyword assistance like that is purely optional.  Keep typing and it will figure it out

Comment: Waiting and then finishing is indeed a case. I just found out that when the following `{}` is not written, android studio cannot switch intelligently. But I may need more reproductions to be sure.